# Email Export: Only specific mailitem properties work

Tags: vbscript, outlook, office365, mapi

I have some code that loops through mailboxes and subfolders to return all mailitems in said folders. It easily reports certain properties like entryID, Creationtime, Subject, and Size. It is important to note we use Office 365. I've noticed the items that work have a listed MAPI analogue in the MSDN documentation.

```
ePSV.write objItem.EntryID & chr(124)
ePSV.write objItem.CreationTime & chr(124)
ePSV.write objItem.Subject & chr(124)
ePSV.write objItem.Size & chr(124)
```

It doesn't seem to be able to pull items like "sender", "to", "CC", or "BCC". My basic question is why? My more pressing question is "what do I need to do to make it work for those basic fields?" Is it a question of configuration that I didn't specify and should? Is there a nomenaclature I'm missing? I am at a point where I can't seem to find the words to google what I don't know. Any and all pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you saying you cannot access the MailIten.To/CC/BCC properties? For the sender, use MailItem.SenderName and SenderEmailAddress properties.

Comment: That does not work --- Object doesn't support this property or method: objItem.SenderName 800A01B6

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with a MailItem object? Where does objItem come from?

Comment: I thought I was...It's related to a for each loop: `Set objInbox = objmailbox.Folders("Inbox")
Set colItems = objInbox.Items
For Each objItem in colItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have other item kinds in the Inbox - ReportItem, MeetingItem, etc. Check that objItem.Class property == 43 (OlObjectClass.olMail).

Comment: Yep. They all equal 43. Thank you for all your effort in this matter. An update: EntryID, CreationTime, Subject, Body, Unread, Impotance, Parent, and Sensitivity all work  --- SentOn, ReceivedTime, SenderEmailAddress, SenderName, To, CC, BCC, Sent, etc. still don't.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried to log the value of the Class property before you access any other property?

Comment: This whole process is bizarre. I'm even getting the "All non-receipt messages are in chinese" bug with this. The fact is, I can pull those fields...with items that existed before we switched over to office 365, nothing after.

Comment: An NDR (represented by the ReportItem object) does not expose the same properties as MailItem. If you are running into the ReportItem.Body problem, you can try to use Redemption and its RDOReportItem.ReportText property - it does not have this problem.

Comment: You were right. I was allowing reportItems. I added an if to restrict it to only mailitems and that did the trick. Thank you for your assistance!